# Is there a way to strip all code from functions in a PHP file so I can use them as a file for Content Assist without showing the actual function?

Tags: php, security, obfuscation

So we have a codebase, which has been developed over the years. As this is a commercial framework, we have several functions in the core PHP files, which are widely used, but won't change that much. We also have some interns on a regular basis, who don't need to have access to the code, but need to view which variables need to be passed and which return to expect.

I want to create a file like standard.php in Eclipse, which only shows the function name and or class names and functions and which variables to pass. I want to create something similar so it eases the development of separate modules, without giving access to the entire codebase.

As I can manually copy the files and strip the code from the functions, this seems to be a bit tedious to do by hand. Also, some functions are being transferred or extended, which means this would need to be done every now and then.

```
/**
 * Check if file is allowed to be added/edited/deleted etc.
 * 
 * @param string $source
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * 
 * @since v9 / WdH / 17-07-2019
 * 
 */
function get_file_allow_rights($source){
    if($source == ""){
        if($_SESSION["did"] > 0){
            $source = get_def("smkb_main_file", "source", "WHERE did = $_SESSION[did]", 1);
        }elseif(isset($_POST["source"])){
            $source = secure($_POST["source"], "string");
        }
    }
    if($source != "" && get_r(get_source_property("modulename", $source), "edit")){
        $allow = true;
    }else{
        $allow = false;
    }

    return $allow;
}
```

should be changed to

```
/**
 * Check if file is allowed to be added/edited/deleted etc.
 * 
 * @param string $source
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * 
 * @since v9 / WdH / 17-07-2019
 * 
 */
function get_file_allow_rights($source){}
```

So is there a function in PHP or some other program like Eclipse to accomplish just this?

Comment: You want to protect the contents of your file from your own developers?

Comment: Yes, although mostly to the people that only work on a certain module. Not only to protect the code, but also to prevent them from diving in too deep. It's mainly to keep the core functions, with years of development from easy copying by interns who stay only for a couple of months.

Comment: Would you not perhaps be better off creating proper documentation out of your script files, using something like https://www.phpdoc.org/, and then hand that to your intern developers …?

Comment: That would a good thing to do anyway, but then you miss the ease of using Content Assist in Eclipse for example.

Comment: To execute the code the need the actual function. You could create a phpfile with empty functions and use that with eclipse for autocomplete etc., but the developer cannot execute or test his code

Comment: Well we have the develop server where we can run part of the code with Source Guardian, so that would allow them to test the code.
And I wonder just if there's a way to easily extract the function names with needed variables to a phpfile whihch I can include in the dev environment.